# django-serializers error inside a virtualenvironment

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install the django serializers-module inside a virutal environment. It gives me an error and I don't know how to get around it. I have tried on 2 computers and a vps and get the same error. It works outside of the virtual environment but not inside.

This is what gets the error:

mkdir test-pi; cd test-pi/; virtualenv -p python3 .; source bin/activate; pip install django-serializers;

This is the error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/owner2/Dev/BELove/src/belove/test-pi/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o2kpa85w/django-serializers/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o2kpa85w/django-serializers/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-o2kpa85w/django-serializers/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o2kpa85w/django-serializers/
Complete output (6 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-o2kpa85w/django-serializers/setup.py", line 56
    print "You probably want to also tag the version now:"
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("You probably want to also tag the version now:")?
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: what module would provide serializers.serialize()

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message, it says that the parenthesis around `print` are absent. In python2, `print` statements without *parenthesis* were allowed but in python3 they were removed.

If you still want to install this package create a virtual environment with python2 as the interpreter and it should work. But I would not suggest this, because the official support for python2 has already been ended last year.

Answer (score 0):

`django-serializers`, the last release 0.6.0 was in 2012. The code is obviously Python2-only.

The [Homepage](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-serializers) was removed.

Resume: outdated abandoned project. Find a better one.